# Laptop AC adapter power cord

Tags: transformer, ac, cables, adapter

I suppose this is probably a stupid question, but my laptop was expensive so I want to make sure I'm protecting it well..

I ordered a second AC adapter for my computer, a used OEM one, but the cord they sent with it (the one that goes from the wall to the adapter box) is not the same as the OEM cord.

The OEM cord says 125V 7A.

The one that came with the used adapter says 125V 2.5A.

The adapter says Input 100-240V 1.8A.

Am I safe to use this cord with this adapter?

Comment: Sorry but this is product usage question. And who knows about safety of a used mains adapter or the cord it came with, it might be broken and fry your laptop or give an electric shock.

Answer (score 1):

**You're safe**

The specifications tell you the intended limits of the cord.

Cord #1 is not meant to be used above 125 volts (U.S. standard) and can handle a maximum of 7 amps for a total power rating of 875 watts (standard formula, power = voltage * current).

Cord #2 is also rated for 125 volts (used in some nations) but is only meant to handle 2.5 amps for a maximum power rating of 312.5 watts.

Your adapter can handle either 125 volts or 240 volts (nice adapter!) with a maximum draw of 1.8 amps. Without knowing exactly what adapter you're using, this usually means that it will step down the voltage during the conversion from AC to DC such that the maximum power consumed is 100 volts * 1.8 amps = 180 watts, which is much lower than the maximum power rating for either cord.

So, you're safe with either cord.

**And a bit more info**

Frankly, your computer is safe no matter what. Let's pretend your non-OEM cord was under-rated (let's say it's only rated for 100 watts). In that case, the cord is most at risk as any wire is just a fuse waiting for the right circumstances to burn it up. An under-sized cord will get hot and eventually destroy itself.

The next item at risk is your adapter. If it's getting insufficient source power due to an undersized cord (because the resistance is too high), that can hurt the adapter. Expensive computers usually have good adapters that have circuitry to protect them from undervoltage conditions.

It's most likely that either the cord or the adapter would go before your computer. Granted, it's not impossible that the computer would be at risk should an undersized cord be used, but it's not impossible for you or I to be hit by a meteor, either. Low odds. Very low odds.

Comment: Both cords were rated for 125V so the details in this answer are wrong.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for pointing that out. I'd missed that the second cord was only rated for 125v.

Comment: +1 Anytime you're into provisioning (cords etc.) we tend to spec that stuff in VA.  To explain it to the novices in a simple way, VA is the entire sinewave the generator or cord must deliver. Watts is the part of the sinewave actually used. It must thermally be set up for VA, because, well, i.e. 10A @ 50% duty cycle causes much more wire heating than 5A continuously.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that. I have to say though, it's kinda weird that 100V @ 1.8A means 180W, since the adapter claims to only be a 130W-er... Maybe that's a continuous power rating rather than maximum? For reference, the adapter is a Dell DA130PM130, came with my XPS15.

Comment: @DC3 The gory details include this: when dealing with establishing power specifications for AC devices we use "Vrms" (voltage root-mean-square) because the power isn't continuous. Vrms = 0.7071 * Vpp (voltage peak-to-peak) = 70.71 * 1.8 = 127.28 which is close enough to 130 watts for government work (and printing 127 on the label would look oddly specific). Since such multiplication is simply a scaling factor in this case, it wasn't worth introducing the complication as it wouldn't change the answer.

Comment: I see. I was also looking at the numbers on on the output side (19.5V, 6.67A), which end up at 130.xx watts. I guess it makes sense that the input and output calculations should end up approximately equal. I'm also assuming the 6.67A output is why the manufacturer provides a 7A input cord..?

Comment: I doubt the output current (which isn't flowing through the cord) has anything to do with the cord specifications. It's more likely that the laptop company got a great deal on cords that met their specifications and the cord just happened to exceed those specifications. The mathematics of economics are nowhere near as predictable as the mathematics of physics.

Comment: Haha fair point. Thanks for the help! Not only do I now know I can use the cord, but I learned a lot to boot!